# How to get value for multivalued get parameter in symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, parameters, get, request

How do you get the value for a get parameter that is a list of values? I tried using `request->query->get('parameter')` but this only returns one value.

Suppose you have a country parameter and want to pass more than 1 value. e.g.  ...`?country=us,gb` using get gives you 'us' only.

I can not find this in the docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to format your query parameter this way

```
country[]=us&country[]=gb
```

Comment: Thank you. This is correct! If query is formatted like this, request->query->get('parameter') will return an array().

Answer (score 1):

From their manual (http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html)

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();

$request->query->get('foo');
```

Edit:

Sorry, I misunderstood your question. You want an array of all GET valiables like $_GET will give you?

That can be done with (will also include POST parameters):

```
 <?php $request->getParameterHolder()->getAll();
```

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. suppose you have a country parameter and want to pass more than 1 value. e.g.  ...?country=us,gb
using get gives you 'us' only. thanks

Comment: Then you need to urlencode your variable and use explode:
yourfile.php?language=us+ru

$languages = explode(" ",  urldecode($_GET['language']) );